ACM-Reference-Format shows arcane errors when multiple @misc references have the same 3-letter prefix
Here's a minimal example for the question:
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@misc{nvidiastream,
  title = {{GPU} Pro Tip: {CUDA} 7 Streams Simplify Concurrency},
  howpublished = {\url{https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency}},
  note = {Accessed: 2024-06}
}

@misc{nvidiamps,
    title={MULTI-PROCESS SERVICE},
    howpublished={\url{https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf}},
    note = {Accessed: 2024-05}
}

@misc{nvidiamig,
    title = {NVIDIA Multi-Instance GPU User Guide},
    howpublished = {\url{https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/pdf/NVIDIA_MIG_User_Guide.pdf}},
    note = {Accessed: 2024-05}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

1\cite{nvidiastream}, 2\cite{nvidiamps}, 3\cite{nvidiamig}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{ref.bib}

\end{document}

When I compile this document, it shows some weird errors that I can't make sense of:
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.24 1\cite{nvidiastream}
                         , 2\cite{nvidiamps}, 3\cite{nvidiamig}.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.24 1\cite{nvidiastream}
                         , 2\cite{nvidiamps}, 3\cite{nvidiamig}.
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.24 1\cite{nvidiastream}
                         , 2\cite{nvidiamps}, 3\cite{nvidiamig}.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.24 1\cite{nvidiastream}
                         , 2\cite{nvidiamps}, 3\cite{nvidiamig}.
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

[...]

(./main.bbl
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.41         {nvidiastream}

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   n
l.41         {nvidiastream}

The relevant lines of main.bbl is:
\bibitem[nvi({[n.\,d.]}a)]%
        {nvidiastream}
 \bibinfo{year}{[n.\,d.]}\natexlab{a}.
\newblock \bibinfo{title}{{GPU} Pro Tip: {CUDA} 7 Streams Simplify
  Concurrency}.
\newblock
  \bibinfo{howpublished}{\url{https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency}}.
\newblock
\newblock
\shownote{Accessed: 2024-06}.

Changing nvidiastream to nvid doesn't resolve, however nvd fixes this for the first reference. Local testing suggests that this triggers for any two @misc references that have the same first 3 letters.
I have no idea why this happens and what the "proper" way to resolve this is. Can anyone help?

Wlcome to TeX.SE.
